# In Javascript, can we load all the files in folder and pass their names as parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

When there is a new file in a subfolder I have to create a href link like below. Right now I am doing it manually.

```
<a href='#' onclick="myfunction('filename')">Filename</a>


<script>
function myfunction(id1)
{
alert(id1);
}
</script>
```

Is there any way to load file names dynamically and automatically create href links of all of them so I can call them by their names?

Thanks

Comment: (Assuming these are files on the server.) Not from the browser, no. You could using server-side code, of course.

Comment: Yes, they are on the server or you say on Github. And I can only make changes in the HTML/JS files.

Comment: Then you can't do it, no.

Comment: You can list files in the folder with javascript, but user has to select the path with `<input type="file" directory />`

Comment: Can you let me know how to do it? It load file names and create a href links with its own name as parameter

Comment: @FlashThunder That doesn't work with server-side files.

Comment: if it's about server side files it's even easier... just get list of files via ajax and server side script